# Differentiation of vector-function

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

Let $f(x) = e^{-x^Tx},$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. What will be the second derivative?

The first is $~f'(x) = 2x^T e^{-x^Tx}$, and when I try to find the second, I confuse.

It will be $$f''(x) = 2e^{-x^Tx}\cdot \mathbb{E}_n-4x^Txe^{-x^Tx}$$ or $$f''(x) = 2e^{-x^Tx}\cdot \mathbb{E}_n-4||x||e^{-x^Tx}\cdot \mathbb{E}_n$$

And can you explain why?

Comment: Use index notation, then it's blatantly obvious how to proceed:
$$\frac{\partial^2 (e^{-x_k x_k})}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$
where repeated indices imply summation. All you need is some chain rule and $\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i}=\delta_{ik}$.